# spotfire ironpython : Append new row to a data-table

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a csv string input 
`string_in="country,100,color"` 
Can anyone please suggest me how to append this input(string_in) to an already existing
 datatable visualisation using ironpython script in spotfire.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to pull in a handful of different functions to pull this off through scripting.  I have my script below but overall what you're looking to do is to set up your input as a data source and then add the rows from that data source to your existing one. I borrowed a good amount from [this](http://spotfire.tibco.com/tips/2014/03/03/streaming-xml-and-json-data-from-the-web-directly-into-spotfire-clients-using-script-controls/) spotfire tutorial by TIBCO and modified it as necessary to get us where you want to be. There may be a couple excess imports you can remove as a result.

I use datTab as an input parameter to the script as the data table we want to add our rows to.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import AddRowsSettings
import System
from System import DateTime
from System.IO import StringReader, StreamReader, StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

#First we need to create your data with some columns. 
#Here I have a comma separated miniature table built up with 
#a commented option for your variable itself. \r\n used for newline
textData = "name,values,category\r\ncountry,100,color\r\n" 
#textData = "col1,col2,col3\r\n" + string_in + "\r\n"

#Memory Stream stuff. Simply just writing our variable 
#into a place we can access to make a data source
stream = MemoryStream()
writer = StreamWriter(stream)
writer.Write(textData)
writer.Flush()
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

#you need settings to tell the system what stuff you're importing.
#here we define it is comma separated and what data types our columns are.
readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
readerSettings.Separator = ","
readerSettings.AddColumnNameRow(0)
readerSettings.SetDataType(0, DataType.String)
readerSettings.SetDataType(1, DataType.Integer)
readerSettings.SetDataType(2, DataType.String)
textDataSource = TextFileDataSource(stream,readerSettings)

#We create some settings here automatically having the system match
#column names for us between the data table and our data source.
settings = AddRowsSettings(datTab,textDataSource)
#And finally we add the rows from our datasource with our settings.
datTab.AddRows(textDataSource,settings)
```

You can of course make this more complex with longer input variables, loop through things to add multiple rows, etc. You can also follow this same process with a URL to a file instead of the memory stream stuff. Depends on your input types.

Let me know if you have any questions. I tried to comment the important parts but there could be further explanation on specific functions if needed.

Edit: See my screenshot below after I added the record a couple different times [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you @clesiemo3. It was most helpful.

Comment: I have a datatable **ALLDataTable** in which few rows are **marked**. I am trying to copy the selected rows to another datatable called **Subset**. 
The logic that I am using is copying the marked rows to a **temp.txt** file and then importing to "Subset"  datatable. There is no runtime error but when i view the newly created Subset datatable there is a msg 
"The selected data table does not contain any columns". Can you kindly assist me in figuring this out.
The code is here- http://ideone.com/fork/PTUAo7

Comment: @diablo8226, You might be best off asking a new question for this rather than a comment on this one. That being said at a glance, it might not be saving to the file as you're just writing to it but not closing it out. I know in my example above I use MemoryStream() rather than a temp file in yours but I'd think they'd be conceptually the same. I'd try the txt file equivalent of flush+seek to 0 if there is one. I don't know off the top of my head. Any reason for tmp file over memory stream?

Comment: no specific reason. I used mem stream and it worked fine. Thanks for your suggestion.